# Color scatter plot by time-grouped values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame `dfp` with columns including `saledate` (in DateTime), `days_to_sell` (as an `int`), and `price` (as an `int`). Using the following code,

```
import pandas as pd
dfp_week = dfp.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(key='saledate', freq='W')).mean()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(dfp['saledate'].values, dfp['price']/1000.0, c=dfp['days_to_sell'].values)

ax.plot_date(dfp_week.index, dfp_week['price']/1000.0, 'r-')
xmin,xmax=plt.xlim()
plt.xlim([datetime.datetime(2015,1,1), xmax])

ax.set_xlabel('Date of sale')
ax.set_ylabel('Most recent asking price (1,000 euros)')
plt.title('Property sales in Amsterdam')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

I generate the following plot:

[image]

The points are colored by `days_to_sell`, but there are so many points one cannot see the trend in the data. On the other hand, if I plot `days_to_sell` itself together with its per-week average,

```
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(dfp['saledate'],dfp['days_to_sell'].values,'.')
plt.plot_date(dfp_week.index, dfp_week['days_to_sell'].values,'r-')
plt.xlabel('Date of sale')
plt.ylabel('Days on the market')
plt.title('Time to sell')
plt.ylim([0,300])
fig2.autofmt_xdate()
```

I get

[image]

which shows a clear recent 'heating up' of the property market. I'd like to color all the points in the plot by the weekly average of `time_to_sell`, rather than by the individual values. How can I do this?